# Re-Enable "Popping" sounds

Tags: 11.10, sound, updates

I want to know why the "popping" sounds were disabled, the ones that sound when I changed the volume, very Mac OSX like.

Is it possible to re-enable them? I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and I loved those sounds by the way.

Regards

Comment: Check that you have an alert sound set in Sound Preferences > Sound Effects, and that the alert volume is turned up.

Comment: The volume is at maximum in Preferences-> Sound Effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it seems that in it's default configuration 11.10 with compiz doesn't *ever* play the system alert sound.

To fix this, open /etc/pulse/default.pa:

`sudo nano /etc/pulse/default.pa`

Around line 158, you should see a line that looks like:

`#load-module module-x11-bell sample=bell-windowing-system`

Remove the leading "#" so that it reads:

`load-module module-x11-bell sample=bell-windowing-system`

Save that file, log out and back in, and you should have your alert sounds back.

Comment: I did that but doesn't seems to help. I think an update deactivated the sounds.

Comment: I tested it on an up-to-date oneiric system and it worked for me.  Can you hear the alert sounds when you select them in sound preferences?

Comment: Yes I can, and my Ubuntu is up to date, every other notification sound seems to work properly

Comment: As a note, this doesn't work in 12.10.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start nautilus with root access by opening terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T)
2. Type `sudo nautilus`
3. Type in the password. (The characters don't show. Just type it and press enter)
4. go to `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo`
5. copy all the files in that folder and paste them at
   `/usr/share/sounds`
6. If you have used dconf editor before to mess with the sound settings in org then return it to default value (freedesktop). If not then skip this step.
7. Close nautilus. Exit terminal. Lougout and Login again.You will have gotten back the popping sound and also other system sounds if they were missing before. (logon sound, warning sounds, etc.)

P.S. Answer obtained from other site not particularly for this problem; however upon trying it out, it worked. Hope it helps you too.

Comment: Last night I received another update to the sound settings and again lost the popping sound. Tried doing again what I mentioned above. It no more worked for me.

Comment: It didn't work for me either, may be the popping sounds are no more by default?

Comment: Surprisingly the popping sound works in gnome shell. could it be a problem with unity?

Comment: I've No idea, I like using unity (:

Comment: Now it works again, I think an update fixed the problem, thanks for all the help (: