# Re-enable pop sound checks in ubuntu gnome 15.10

Tags: gnome, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I tried https://askubuntu.com/a/86750/469695 but it didn't work.

It stopped working when I re-installed PulseAudio. I also tried toggling sound effect in sound settings.

Another strange thing is when I go to the output tab and click "Test Speakers" If I click test on front left or front right nothing plays. But my sound does work when playing media.

I'm sure it's missing the files it's supposed to play. I just don't know where they are or where to download them. I have backups I could restore files from. Unless it's easier to fix this another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just restored the files from backup.

/usr/share/sounds/gnome/ is the directory missing the files.

Pop sounds are back!

I did have to reboot for them to start working.